# Setting up postgres Contrib packages

Tags: nitrousio

I created a box on Nitrous.io and installed postgres database using autoparts. Now I want to enable UUID so was trying to add the uuid-ossp extension when I run the command 
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;

I get the following error
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/home/action/.parts/packages/postgresql/9.2.4/share/postgresql/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory

It appears like the uuid-ossp extension is not included with the postgres installation.

I thought if I can provide the required files it would work and I copied out the following files into the above folder - 
uuid-ossp--1.0.sql
uuid-ossp--unpackaged--1.0.sql
uuid-ossp.control

Now when I tried creating the extension I got a new error - 
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory

Looks like I am missing something. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks